# How does this timing aboard the Obra Dinn make sense?

Tags: return-of-the-obra-dinn

In Return of the Obra Dinn, looking through some of the death scenes, I am perplexed as to how the timing works.

In Escape I, we hear the captain has just come up from the hold after chasing away the monster, and we see people (including the captain) emerging from the lower decks. The dialogue seems to indicate that very little time has passed since the end of Doom. In (chronologically) later Escape scenes, we see that the captain comes across four people escaping in the last boat, and one escapee being killed.

However, in The Bargain, we see the captain

> negotiating violently for the dismissal of the kraken, and after he has left, the final mermaid is carried out by Paul and Davey, and after that the doctor shoots the monkey with Paul looking over his shoulder. Paul, Davey and the doctor are all with the ladies and the boat in Escape.

How did they do all of that in the time it took the captain to walk up two decks?

Comment: This isn't an answer because I haven't done this for the fates in question, but I believe the timepiece's hands display the time of death when you activate it on a body. This might help elucidate the timeline.

Answer (score 1):

I believe at least several hours pass between the events of The Bargain Part 3, and The Escape, Part 1.

I speculate that the following flow of events occurs.:

> - The Doom, Part 8 occurs.
>
>  - The storm dies down, and the Kraken leaves.
>
>  - The Captain probably throws two of the shells overboard.
>
>  - The wreckage is cleared off the deck.
>
>  - The living casualties are taken to cabins for treatment, and the dead casualties are prepared for burial at sea.
>
>  - The Escape plan is hatched.
>
>  - The Bargain, Part 4: The last surviving Mermaid is freed through the efforts of the Third Mate and the two stewards, costing the former his life, and locking the door.
>
>  - The Bargain, Part 5: The Surgeon, having been told by Moss about what happened, sets up the corpse chain through his monkey.
>
>  - Someone tells the Captain that the Third Mate is dead in the Lazarette, and he heads down with the last Midshipman to see for himself.
>
>  - Those in on the Escape plan start moving for the boat while the Captain is in the hold.
>
>  - The Escape, Part 1: The Bosun wakes up in the Officer's Mess, is told what happened at the end of The Doom, and dies of his wounds. The Captain and the Midshipman start heading back to the upper deck, after failing to get into the Lazarette.

If, in The Escape, Part 1, the captain is coming back up from checking on the results after all the events of The Bargain,  rather than coming up after the Bargain, Part 3, there's enough time for the setup for The Escape, Part 2.